# How can I load chinese fasttext model with gensim?

Tags: gensim, fasttext

While trying to load chines fasttext model(cc.zh.300.bin) with gensim, I stucked with following error

> UnicodeDecodeError:'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xba in position 0:
>   invalid start byte

Anyone can help me, please? Detailed error below :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format()` method only loads files in the plain words-and-vectors format used by Google's original `word2vec.c` code. It would not be expected to work on a FastText-format file.

You should try instead the method `load_facebook_vectors()` that's specifically for FastText format files:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#gensim.models.fasttext.load_facebook_vectors

For some uses, the alternate `load_facebook_model()` might also be appropriate:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#gensim.models.fasttext.load_facebook_model

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll use load_facebook_vectors() since it is faster